# using php to retrieve raspberry pi unique id

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to retrieve raspberry pi unique id using php. I'm able to retrieve the info using terminal but not sure how to retrieve using php.
Hope experts here can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: this is the link to retrieve id from raspberry pi via terminal

http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/how-do-i-get-the-serial-number

Comment: Implement it in a similar way to to the Python, but using PHP and this command: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php